# How to tell my manager I have lost interest in job due to I.T. problem

Tags: professionalism, communication

I had been working for a company for almost 2 months. It has been very stressing situation as the I.T has so much problem setting me up that it took 1 month and 5 days just to get me the software I needed to code and setup, The Line Manage was frustrated, the PM was frustrated because I.T. has rules that even smallest software install need to be approved, risk assessed etc.

During this time, I was awarded scholarship from government of U.K. to advance my career, which I talked to my manager few weeks after I started but he said, it is not valuable to us and I rejected it. Now again by chance and last chance I got offer for the scholarship again but since I started at company and now I have lost my flare of coding or working because till now, my system isn't ready and I lost track of time as a fresh start. I been part of daily scrum, long call//screen share of other development senior trying to get me started but failing.

How can I tell my Line Manager that I want to leave as the work as I don't feel passionate about it given what had happen/is happening. I like to come back to the company (and not burn my bridges) when they are ready as I feel like during these 50 days my skills and knowledge in programming has became worse.

Comment: What are you doing all day long ? You could have used this time to sharpen your skills and knowledge.

Comment: @Maxime being on call all day, while the team other team member tried to help me but it ended up in frustration and emailing the I.T. yes I did learn much of the language they used but I couldn't apply it because the IDE wasn't setup for a months and more (still I cannot use my web server locally)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Have you made the decision to quit in order to pursue full time education?

Comment: @NathanCooper I want to know how to send message across to my manager that I gave up my chance of advancing my career first (as I discussed with him) but due to company infrastructure and the rules, It is hard for me to work (impossible) and I would rather focus on education but I do not want be sound rude as in, "I m leaving company coz for 1.5 month they can't sort out my system"

Comment: To be blunt, the company probably doesn't care about how your loss of motivation is affecting you personally. If you've identified yourself as unmotivated and wish to leave then just leave; you'd be saving them much headache. If they conduct an exit interview then let them know otherwise you're just a child stomping their feet.

Answer (score 15):

I'm assuming that this is the same 3-month course opportunity you discussed [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/171793/how-to-convince-company-that-i-want-to-do-this-course-while-saving-my-job)

> How can I tell my Line Manager that I want to leave as the work as I don't feel passionate about it given what had happen/is happening. I like to come back to the company (and not burn my bridges) when they are ready as I feel like during these 50 days my skills and knowledge in programming has became worse.

Allow me to be blunt here - you don't mention what the course actually is but you're 10 **years** into your career so unless you're talking about a highly valuable, in-demand professional certification then a 3 month course isn't going to do jack-all for your employability. If anything another short-tenure job is going to do significantly more harm than the course could ever counteract.

The situation and all of the roadblocks at your current job certainly sound frustrating and I can't blame your for feeling a bit frustrated. But your position there doesn't sound precarious at all, if anything it sounds as though your manager and the PM are fully aware that the hold-ups aren't on your side. Bail now however and all potential future employers will see is a 2 month job that went nowhere, taken with your prior history of short stays in jobs that's going to be extremely damning.

If you really want to take the course then leave and do that, no hand wringing about "passion" or "interest", just say you've decided you don't want to miss out on the course opportunity. But I highly doubt you're going to be able to have your cake and eat it here. You've already discussed this course with your current employer and they haven't seen any value in you doing it so there's unlikely to be any incentive for them to hang around for a few months while you do that. If you leave you **have** to accept that in all likelihood this job is **gone**.

Comment: thanks for being blunt and I welcome that, problem with me is I have too many gaps in my cv and recently during pademic I have lost more than I have gained in terms of respect, knowledge, wisdom and relationship. I had gaps in my CV because I do not have good knowledge of JS and JS is core to front end now, with the course I did attend for 2 weeks it helped me massively, not only JS but also understand SQL (which I did back in teenage n no one explained me to so well). This will boost my career, my only fear had been and is that while sitting idle

Comment: @localhost Use your current idle time to learn, practice, learn some more. For pity's sake, **Keep the job you have**, *that* will boost your career.

Comment: @localhost You seem to have the habit of making bad career decisions, so take motosubatsu's advice and try to learn from your mistakes - it might be your last chance before retiring as unemployed.

Comment: @localhost You said in your other question that you quit your last two jobs. Can you really blame all the gaps on your lack of knowledge? It sounds like you're just unwilling to stay in a job.

Comment: @Kat my last one crap. before that I was made redundant but it was great, prior to that I learned a lot! This curent job is good (in term of project n learning but system is too old for me to work, imagine sitting 2 months just sitting n not able to do anything and attend meeting which divert my attention, in short my unwillingness has a reason, and yes blame falls on me too as I lack intrapersonal skills which make me not favourable etc

Comment: @Chris u r correct, I had been landing in wrong places but those good ones don't last long. I am a nervous person due to work I did during 4-6 years of my career with PM who made me feel I should know everything and if I don't I m lucky not be fired and I grew with that mentality until it became a habit thus the rebound effect but later on I learned that u don't need to know everything in I.T. (as some companies took me without knowledge of X or Y and I learned on the job)

Comment: @localhost honestly, you're coming across very much as if you don't know what you want (or DON'T want, which is sometimes almost as important). Have you considered doing those exercises where you sit down and figure out what's important to you work and career-wise? Some of them are pretty simple 2 column things (satisfactors / dissatisfactors) while others are a series of questions that come out with rankings and etc.

Comment: @localhost almost everyone would be annoyed with that situation, but almost no one would quit over it if they didn't have a better job to go to. Suck it up and give the job a chance. Work isn't all fun, that's why they pay you.